# If events are dependent how does probability of intersection of the events relate to individual event probabilities?

Tags: probability

$P(A) = \frac{4}{5}, P(B|A) = \frac{1}{2}$. $A$ and $B$ are dependent (NOT independent) events.

P(A $\cap$ B ) > P(A)P(B) ?

I know $P(A \cap B)\not= P(A)P(B)$. And that $A \cap B \subset A$, $B$. Does that mean it is false or do we not have enough information?

Comment: Can you figure out what $P(A\cap B)$ is?

Comment: Yes, P(A $\cap$ B) = 2/5. Does not help.We don't have P (A|B) or P(B).

Comment: Yes, $P(A\cap B)=\frac25.$ So your question $$P(A\cap B)\gt P(A)P(B)?$$ reduces to $$\frac25\gt\frac45P(B)?$$ or $$P(B)\lt\frac12?$$ I'd call that a step forward, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had a number generator that spits out integers between $1$ and $5$ with each number being equally likely to come out. Let $A$  be the event that the number that comes out is $1,2,3,$ or $4$. Let $B$ be the event that the number that comes out is $1,2$ or $5$.

Then $P(A)=\frac{4}{5}$, $P(B|A)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(B)=\frac{3}{5}$, and $P(A\cap B)=\frac{2}{5}$. However $P(A)P(B)=\frac{12}{25}>P(A \cap B)$. So in the scenario you have set up, it is certainly not true that $P(A \cap B)>P(A)P(B)$ in general.

Comment: Yes, I found counter examples showing both greater and lesser P(A∩B) compared to P(A)P(B). Thank you!